# Webpack Module Federation fails with Next JS when using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, styled-components, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to get Webpack Module Federation working with a NextJS app where the federated module is using styled-components. My configuration is working as expected if I'm only using react and react-dom but using styled-components gives me these errors:

```
It looks like there are several instances of 'styled-components' initialized in this application. This may cause dynamic styles to not render properly, errors during the rehydration process, a missing theme prop, and makes your application bigger without good reason.
```

and

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I have tried the different approaches to resolve styled-components to a single instance by modifying the Webpack config in both the host and remote apps, but all seem to fail.

Here is my current configuration:

Federated modules repo (webpack.config.js):

```
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    port: 3001,
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: "auto",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          plugins: [
            ["babel-plugin-styled-components", { pure: true, ssr: true }],
          ],
          presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "remoteLib",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./Button": "./src/Button",
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
        "styled-components": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["styled-components"],
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Consuming NextJS app Webpack config (next.config.js):

```
webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = options.webpack.container;

    config.plugins.push(
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            remotes: {
                'federated-components': 'remoteLib@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js'
            }
        })
    );

    return config;
}
```

Comment: Just a random shot in the dark, have you tried completely uninstalling and removing it from node_modules and package.json.  I'd guess that webpack is probably loading it from external and it's also already in the project so it's trying to bundle it twice, or perhaps doesn't know where to import it from or something.  I have no idea how module federation works but if you're loading it from an external library it would make sense to say it shouldn't be in the project as well.

Comment: No dice there. It's required to be in the dependencies in order to build the remote app. By defining it as "shared" in the MF plugin config it should be loading the version provided by the host app but that doesn't appear to be the result I'm getting.